# create a function to get value from array of object

Tags: function, loops, if-statement

I want to create a function that if I call function(ashfaq) show me age and phone to. Like (ashfaq, 28,0345)
my code looks like this;
let arr = [{
name: 'ashfaq',
age: 28,
phone: '0345',
},{
name: 'md',
age: 22,
phone: '0344',
},{
name: 'usman',
age: 23,
phone: '0343',
}];

remember I want to use an only function, loop, and if-else

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: yes I try this function test(arr, prop) {
  var d = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < d; i++) {
      console.log(arr[i][prop]);
  }
}

test( arr,'age');

Comment: in loop you have to first check which name is passed through parameter and then if it matches the same name then you have to return name,age and phone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let arr = [{ name: 'ashfaq', age: 28, phone: '0345', },{ name: 'md', age: 22, phone: '0344', },{ name: 'usman', age: 23, phone: '0343', }]

const returnData = function(array,name){
    
    let dataArray = array
    
    for(let i = 0 ; i < dataArray.length ; i++){
        if((dataArray[i].name).toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()){
            return `${dataArray[i].name},${dataArray[i].age},${dataArray[i].phone}`
        }
    }
    
}

console.log(returnData(arr,'ashfaq'))
```

Try this think this is what you need